# Thermal Energy / Capacity Help

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to come up with a simple metric for my hvac data that represents an outdoor to indoor metric versus heating/cooling runtime.

Obviously the simplest, but incomplete, is just look at outdoor minus indoor temperature and average it across 30 minutes and see how long your equipment was running during that time and in what mode.

The better answer is to incorporate humidity differences, barometric pressure, and volume. My assumptions were to assume the following:
1. The average barometric temperature would be the same both inside and outside.
2. Outside would have infinite volume.
3. Air is 20% oxygen and rest is 80% nitrogen
4. Use outdoor humity and temperature from a service, indoor is provided by the thermostat.

How do I calculate the amount of thermal energy is in the air outdoor and indoor at any given time with the goal of subtracting indoor from outdoor. This will allow me to see how much the thermostat is commanding which mode based on the differential of outdoor to indoor.

Thoughts? Equation help? Suggestions?

Thanks!
Frank